# Performance Tuning for large queries on Apache Drill

Tags: parquet, apache-drill

Am trying to execute large queries on apache drill and its taking more than 1 hour to run, even though CPUs, memory and I/O are all under utilized.

Size of underlying data in parquet format: 30 GB

Cluster Size: Single node

RAM: 512 GB, 300GB assigned to drill.

CPU: 48

File System: MapR

What are the possible tuning parameters that one can check to improve the performance of apache drill?

Comment: Where does your data reside? HDFS, S3 or local file system?

Comment: Data is on MapR file system

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apache drill bad performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583012/apache-drill-bad-performance)

Comment: Please provide an example of your sql command.