# How to improve Drill Performance

Tags: hive, hbase, apache-drill

I have one table in hive data warehouse when I am reading that table using drill,using this query-

```
select row_key,play load,update_time from parsed_table where update_time between '2017-01-01 00:00:00' and '2017-01-01 23:59:59' and  web-socket_key='359569050289017/AINU'
```

It fetches 3,890 rows in 15.288 seconds. Could anyone suggest what should I do to improve query performance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apache drill bad performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583012/apache-drill-bad-performance)

Comment: What is the source of data ?